# Android .apk app installing on "Memo" or "Calendar" instead of "Installation program for package" On Tablet

Tags: android, installation, tablet, samsung-mobile

I have got a very strange problem when I try to install my signed .apk app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1" white. When I have downloaded my app on my phone I get two option: either install directly with "Installation program for package" or scan the app with an anti-virus app (which is completely normal).

However on the tablet I get two completely different install-options: The Samsung apps: "Memo" or "Calendar".

Why can't I install the app on the tablet when I can install it on my phone.

FYI I'm doing a free version too, and I could install that one without any problems on my tablet!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of your firmware.